# Error: Failed to lookup view "location.ejs" in views directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am getting error -

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "location.ejs" in views directory 
"e:\NodeJs_Project\geolocationProject\views"
 at Function.render
```

Please help solve the error.

**server.js**

```
var express  =   require('express');
var app  =   express();
const path = require('path');

//Middleware express. For session also.
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var session = require('express-session');
var restify = require('restify');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(express.static ('public'));

var cors = require('cors')  // Not required.

app.use(cors());  
app.use(express.static('public'))


app.set('views',path.join(__dirname+'/views'));

app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('location.ejs');
  });


app.listen(8080,(req,res)=>{
    console.log('server running on port 8080')
})
```

I even tried -

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views/');

and

app.set('views', __dirname + 'views');

but to no avail

NodeJs_Project
 ..geolocationProject
   ..views
     ..location.ejs

Comment: the error is saying there is no file named `location.ejs` in your `views` folder

Comment: The file is present. I shall post the file structure in my question

Comment: `app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').renderFile);` change to `app.engine('ejs', require('ejs'))` and you can just use `res.render('location')` without the `.ejs` extension

Comment: If i use it - app.engine('ejs', require('ejs'));. I get error - callback function required.

Comment: maybe change the import as `const ejs = require('ejs')` and then `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`

Comment: Sorry .. no difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190978/discussion-between-naga-elixir-jar-and-sucheta-shrivastava).

Answer (score 0):

Hi just saw ur question i was also going through this i will suggest u using app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
This worked for me personally and one more thing i was going through docs and i got to know that there is no need to explicitly do that if u are using ejs express automatically looks up for views directory but ya if u wanna name that something else then u can follow the above pattern...i hope it works for u..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).